# Copy/Paste Keybindings Don't Work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, copy-paste, key-bindings

I have the following keybindings in my MainWindow:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+O"/>
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+S"/>

<KeyBinding Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+C"/>
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding PasteCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+V"/>
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding CutCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+X"/>
```

The Open and the Save keybindings work fine... the rest do nothing when I hit the key combination. There are no binding errors in the output. I also have buttons on my menu bound to the same commands and they work. Is there an issue using commands that have a CanExecute method associated with them? I an using .Net 4.0. Any ideas as to why the clipboard actions wouldn't work?

**Update:**
If I bind something else (like OpenCommand) to Ctrl+C it works. If I bind CopyCommand to a different gesture it still does not work. So it seems to be a problem with the command. That is strange though because my copy button works fine bound to the same CopyCommand. Here is the CopyCommand code that it is bound to:

```
public ICommand CopyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.copyCommand == null)
            {
                this.copyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => this.Copy(),
                    param => this.Copy_CanExecute());
            }

            return this.copyCommand;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you bind the CopyCommand etc to another gesture do they work?

Comment: If I bind another command to Ctrl+C it works, if I bind CopyCommand to another gesture it does not work. So it is something with the command. I'll add the code I have for the command. Seems strange though because the Copy button I have works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only execute commands where `CanExecute` returns `true`, might be one reason why they do no execute.

Another possible reason is local handling of the respective gestures, as `TextBoxes` do by default. You can override this by re-declaring the `KeyBindings` locally with your own command.

Comment: CanExecute is returning true (I can tell because my buttons that are also bound to that command get enabled and disabled correctly).

Comment: @KrisTrip: Maybe the command is handled somewhere else then? e.g. a TextBox may override said `KeyBindings`.

Comment: Oh good call, the thing i am trying to copy is a TextBox (readonly) within a treeview. Is there any way to disable that on a TextBox?

Comment: @KrisTrip: There has been a question about that, i for one just suggested to overwrite the existing keybindings (redeclare them the same way as in the window). There might be more elegant solutions..

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Since my textboxes were defined in a datatemplate I just added the KeyBindings there. If you update your answer, I'll mark as correct.

Comment: @KrisTrip: Edited it, if you think it still ain't perfect you can suggest an edit to it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

this works fine. In my MainWindow.xaml file, I add two keyBinding commands for illustration

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindowCommandBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+O"/>
        <!--<KeyBinding Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+S"/>-->
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+C"/>
        <!--<KeyBinding Command="{Binding PasteCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+V"/>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding CutCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+X"/>-->
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs file, I initialize my DataContext as follow.

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowContext();
    }
```

The MainWindowContext class is defined as follow

```
class MainWindowContext
{
    RelayCommand _openCommand;
    public ICommand OpenCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_openCommand == null)
            {
                _openCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => this.Open(),
                    param => this.Open_CanExecute());
            }
            return _openCommand;
        }

        set { _openCommand = (RelayCommand) value; }

    }

    RelayCommand _copyCommand;
    public ICommand CopyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_copyCommand == null)
            {
                _copyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => this.Copy(),
                    param => this.Copy_CanExecute());
            }
            return _copyCommand;
        }

        set { _copyCommand = (RelayCommand)value; }

    }

    private bool Copy_CanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private object Copy()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Copy command executed");
        return null;
    }

    private bool Open_CanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private object Open()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Open command executed");
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I execute, it works fine. You can see which command has been executed in your console.
Please tell me if I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

There are some key combinations you can not use because windows already uses them. I think Ctrl+c/v is one of them.